# having trouble using stack function-R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have to below data frame(df):

```
> df
            a           b           c           d           e
1 0.007706719 0.007706719 0.007706719 0.007706719 0.007706719
2 0.007247824 0.007706719 0.007706719 0.007706719 0.007706719
3 0.006716007 0.007026198 0.007706719 0.007545972 0.007449816
4 0.008652269 0.009386124 0.010247610 0.009349975 0.009236069
5 0.011559262 0.011755480 0.011594489 0.012190477 0.012029822
```

With dput form:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(a = structure(c(0.00770671877718716, 0.00724782403499172, 
0.00671600662378172, 0.00865226924460998, 0.0115592617816976), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(86400, 172800, 259200, 345600, 432000
), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 
1L)), b = structure(c(0.00770671877718716, 0.00770671877718716, 
0.00702619830053687, 0.00938612381100274, 0.0117554804029797), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(86400, 172800, 259200, 345600, 432000
), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 
1L)), c = structure(c(0.00770671877718716, 0.00770671877718716, 
0.00770671877718716, 0.0102476100939602, 0.011594488602641), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(86400, 172800, 259200, 345600, 432000
), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 
1L)), d = structure(c(0.00770671877718716, 0.00770671877718716, 
0.00754597153109664, 0.00934997518422475, 0.0121904772376695), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(86400, 172800, 259200, 345600, 432000
), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 
1L)), e = structure(c(0.00770671877718716, 0.00770671877718716, 
0.00744981620477373, 0.00923606895843253, 0.0120298215459641), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(86400, 172800, 259200, 345600, 432000
), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 
1L))), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
> stack(df)
```

I want to reshape df using stack function(column headers to rows). But I get the below error:

```
> stack(df)
Error in stack.data.frame(df) : no vector columns were selected
```

I want to reshape as below:

```
a 0.007706719 
a 0.007247824 
a 0.006716007 
a 0.008652269 
a 0.011559262 
b 0.007706719 
b 0.007706719 
b 0.007026198 
b 0.009386124 
b 0.011755480 
c 0.007706719 
c 0.007706719 
c 0.007706719 
c 0.010247610 
c 0.011594489 
d 0.007706719 
d 0.007706719
d 0.007545972
d 0.009349975
d 0.012190477
e 0.007706719
e 0.007706719
e 0.007449816
e 0.009236069
e 0.012029822
```

How can I solve the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What should your output be?

Comment: @Onyambu, I added the output

Comment: Do you want to maintain the classes?

Comment: @Onyambu I just want to reshape df as the last data frame. I mean, I want to move column names into rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

df is a data frame whose columns are xts objects. Probably it should never have been created in the first place and instead a single xts object should have been created with multiple columns.

At any rate, we can cbind the columns of df into a single xts object, x, convert that to a data frame and then stack will work.  Alternately, use fortify.zoo in place of stack which will also give a column for the times.

```
library(xts)

x <- do.call("cbind", df) # xts object

stack(as.data.frame(x))[2:1]
# or
fortify.zoo(x, melt = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you want to reshape columns to rows.. does this do what you're looking for?

```
t(df)
```

This just transposes the data.frame, so columns become rows and rows become columns

[EDIT] Try this:

```
data.frame(Rows=sort(rep(colnames(df),nrow(df))),Values=as.numeric(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `df` contains columns with class `zoo`. Thus you have to strip this off. Any of the following can do:

```
stack(lapply(df, c))

stack(data.frame(as.matrix(df)))

data.frame(ind = names(df)[col(df)], value = unlist(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

May this work for you?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = everything(),
    names_to = "ind",
    values_to = "values"
  ) %>% 
  unnest("values")
```

Output:

```
   ind    values
   <chr>   <dbl>
 1 a     0.00771
 2 b     0.00725
 3 c     0.00672
 4 d     0.00865
 5 e     0.0116 
 6 a     0.00771
 7 b     0.00771
 8 c     0.00703
 9 d     0.00939
10 e     0.0118 
# ... with 15 more rows
```